# XSS vulnerability in React.js

Tags: reactjs, xss

I'm doing the Secure Code Warrior course for React.js and I was wondering why this code was **not** vulnerable (I mean the line containing dangerouslySetInnerHTML):

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import PostTagList from "./PostTagList";

/**
* Single Post List Component
* */
const PostListItem = ({ id, title, text, author, tags }) => (
  <li className="list-group-item post-list-item">
    <Link to={`/post/${id}`}>
      Title: {title}
      <br />
      <p
        className="post-tem-short-content"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }}
      />
      <PostTagList tags={tags} />
      <span className="pl-it-author">by {author}</span>
    </Link>
  </li>
);
PostListItem.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  author: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  tags: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default PostListItem;
```

Comment: Is `text` some user input?

Comment: As it is, that example would be vulnerable to XSS attacks - unless `text` is coming from a 'safe' source. (even then `text` should really be sanitised with something like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)

Comment: @Camilo that could be the trick, to know I'd need to check everywhere in the app where this component is used :(